# Salesforce Object is missing on the Docusign Salesforce Connect Object Salesforce Object

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I have a new Custom Object in Salesforce, but he is not showing on the Docusign Salesforce Connect Object Salesforce Object List.

I'm looking for it but I have not success.

Thanks

Rafael

Comment: Are you saying the custom tag does not show within docusign esignature admin when trying to add a custom tag? Can you try adding a regular custom tag on a regular salesforce object, do you get any error?

Comment: Hi @bendowlingtech,
No, the object was not showing in the list of Salesforce Object inside of Docusign (Salesforce Connect Object section) but I found where is the problem.
The problem is, the user does not have the permission to see these object inside Salesforce, so after giving access to the object  for the user, now the object is showing in the list

Answer (score 0):

The object may not be visible with your current permission set.
You should check the object settings for your custom object.

SF Admin Panel > Setup > Users > Permission Sets > Your_permission set > Object Settings

If the object is enabled / visible on that screen you should be good to go.

Alternatively, there's a [ready-made SF app available for Docusign](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000001taX4EAI).